# How to do Kafka-Spark-MongoDb integration efficiently

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am writing a Spark 2.4 transformation for spark benchmarking which will get JSON Streams from Kafka topic and need to dump it to MongoDB. I can do it using Java MongoClient, but data can be huge such as 1 Million records coming through multiple threads from Kafka. Spark processes it very fast but mongo write is very slow.

```
            SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").
            setAppName("JavaDirectKafkaStreaming"); 

    sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled","true");
    JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(2));

    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "loacalhost:9092");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "2");
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("poc-topic");

    final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(streamingContext,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.<String, String> Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    JavaPairDStream<String, String> jPairDStream = stream
            .mapToPair(new PairFunction<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String, String>() {
                public Tuple2<String, String> call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value());
                }
            });

    jPairDStream.foreachRDD(jPairRDD -> {

        jPairRDD.foreach(rdd -> {
            System.out.println("value=" + rdd._2());
            if (rdd._2() != null) {
                System.out.println("inserting=" + rdd._2());

                Document doc = Document.parse(rdd._2());
                // List<Document> list = new ArrayList<>();
                // list.add(doc);
                db.getCollection("collection").insertOne(doc);
                System.out.println("Inserted Data Done");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Got no data in this window");
            }

        });
    });
    streamingContext.start();
    streamingContext.awaitTermination();
```

Where

```
             MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
             MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("mongodb");
```

I expect to speed up the mongo Operation,how to achiever multithreading for mongo write? (should I use MongoClientOptions for minconnection per host?)

Also is the approach taken is correct to use MongoDriver or it should done by MonogSpark connector or By spark writestream() API's. If yes how to write each rdd as separate record in mongo any example in Java?

Comment: Any reason you want to write Spark code instead of using something like Kafka Connect?

Comment: I need to check the performance when my raw data flows from Kafka to Spark and the data transformations happens in spark storing the result to mongoDb.

Comment: Typically the pattern people like using is Topic->Transform->New_Topic (using Kafka Streams API or Spark for example), then from that new topic, you can send to many other datasources, one of which could be Mongo and using Connect... In other words, separarte your concerns here. One app to transform the data. Another app to sink to Mongo. Besides, there are SparkSQL writers for Mongo, so you really shouldn't be using `foreachRDD` manually if youre using Spark 2.x

Comment: Ok, thanks I will check this. Also,I am using spark 2.4, can you point me to some examples for SparkSQL for mongoDB?

Comment: It's directly on the Mongo website... https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/v1.1/spark-sql/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "efficiently" because there are a lot of factors at play here.

For example, Kafka partitions and total Spark executors are just two values that need tuned to accomodate for thoughput.

I do see you are using the `ForEachWriter`, which is a good way to do it, but maybe not the best considering you're doing constantly calling `insertOne`, compared to using Spark Structed Streaming to begin with, reading from Kafka, manipulating your data into a Struct object, then [using SparkSQL Mongo Connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/v1.1/spark-sql/) to directly dump to Mongo collections (which I would guess uses Mongo transactions, and inserts mutiple records at a time)

---

Also worth mentioning, Landoop offers a MongoDB [Kafka Connect Sink](https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/mongo.html#mongodb-setup), which requires one config file, and no Spark code to be written.